# How to deprecate redundant keys in Django REST for serializer?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have:

models.py:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

resources.py:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta(object):
        model = models.MyModel

class MyModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = models.MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LinkSerializer
```

I can do following request:
curl -X "POST" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name": "name1", "redundant": "value"}'  http://127.0.0.1:8000/mymodel/

And I will get 201.

My question is: "How I can deprecate redundant keys?" Keys that model(or MyModelSerializer) doesn't contain.

UPDATE.
Well, I've created following mixin:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework import exceptions as rest_framework_exceptions

class RedundantSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    """This Mixin should provide possibility for checking redundant keys

    in request data
    """

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        _writable_fields_names = [
            field.source for field in self._writable_fields
        ]
        errors = {}
        for key in data.keys():
            if key not in _writable_fields_names:
                errors[key] = "This field is redundant"
        if errors:
            raise rest_framework_exceptions.ValidationError(errors)
        return super(RedundantSerializer, self).to_internal_value(data)
```

and inherited it in Serializer above:

```
class MyModelSerializer(RedundantSerializer, serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta(object):
        model = models.MyModel
```

Comment: Can you try add `fields` into meta class of your serializer? See if that helps..

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to override the view create / update and compare the keys from request.data against those from the serializer.validated_data (easily done with a set):

```
deprecated_keys = set(request.data.keys()) - set(serializer.validated_data)
```

Then you'll deal with whatever logic you want after that: return a 400 error with the deprecated keys for example.